# 100% width div gets cut off when I scroll right if my browser window is smaller than div's content

Tags: css, html, scroll, width

I had a problem on my own site with a `<div>` that is supposed to have 100% width. The code for it is shown below.

```
#myDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    background: #f48;
}
```

This works great except for the following issue:

When my browser window is smaller than the `<div>`'s content, and I scroll to the right then my `<div>` will move left with the rest of the page rather than occupying 100% of the width of the page's scrollable area.

This issue has been bugging me for a few hours and just recently I realized that many other sites have the same issue. Including Facebook.com and Stackoverflow.com just take a look at my snapshots below.

**Facebook's Bug:**

[image: Facebook's 100% width bug]

**Stackoverflow's Bug:**

[image: Stackoverflow's 100% width bug]

Answer (score 8):

Ok, solved it! I just have to set the `min-width` property to the width of that `<div>`'s content.

Thanks anyways guys!

Comment: P.S. I am uber-surprised why facebook and stackoverflow don't do this.

Comment: I am having basically the same issue on my company's site. The `width` is 100% and `min-width` is 990 px, but if the browser is narrower than the content, and the content wider than 990 px, I get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

How you tried this? Tested it in IE7:

```
html, body {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `width: auto;` and it's helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue for myself with `display: inline-block`.  Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/z01g0r2d/1/ . Note if you try to set width of the long content as, for example, `200%` the solution stops working.