# div doesn't stretch 100% width of a page if window width narrower then the rest of the content

Tags: css, html

If I resize browser window (Newest Chrome in my case) so it gets horizontal scrollbar then the header div gets "cut off". In that case scrolling to right reveals some empty space. This is because the main content other then header have fixed width.

But the header div has 100% width and div is a block element by default also so it should stretch by itself to the 100% of the page width. Why it is not doing so? Shouldn't it be the default behavior? And why StackOverflow team didn't fix it?

The problem I found on many pages, including StackOverflow:

[image]

So I've been googling, even found a solution for a problem but not satisfactory enough. The solution is to set the [min-width property to the width of that 's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554813/100-width-div-gets-cut-off-when-i-scroll-right-if-my-browser-window-is-smaller). But isn't there a better solution?

I'm searching for a better solution, if any? Also I'm searching for an reasonable explanation why div's default behavior to stretch 100% of the width doesn't apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see a white space because, somewhere on the page, most likely under the header element, there is an element which is bigger than 100% – that's why you see the horizontal scrollbar.

The header infact is 100%, which means it's shorter than the full width of the document - therefore the white space.

To debug, I usually open the inspector and start from the bottom to the top and delete the sibling of the header, one by one, till I get to the point where everything is no more white space. At that point you know the problem is with the last element you just deleted. Try to look for errors in that particular element.

Comment: This part I got also, but the key problem here is **bigger than 100%**. Shouldn't 100% be full width not only visible part?

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the body element and you'll see that it only extends as far as the viewport. The topbar-wrapper is 980px fixed width, and its parent with the black background, topbar, is 100% (of body). topbar also needs a width of 980px, or the body element needs min-width: 980px...here on the StackOverflow site *(looks like you found a bug)*

This is a problem I often found on builds I was reviewing from freelancers, where they forget to shrink their browser down. The full-width sections usually need min-widths, if the site isn't fluid and there are fixed-width elements.

Comment: But even if I remove all widths from header and its parents, the problem remain (so only natural div's behavior remains). So basically the body element cannot have bigger width then viewport if not explicitly defined? But I don't want to define fixed width on body, what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The "cut-off" div has a width of 100% of the visible area, so everything is ok.
The Problem is, that the content is overflowing and you are now able to scroll to the 120% width.

To fix this behavior und stretch your "cut-off" div always over the full width of the page, you can apply some css:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: I think I prefer min-width  more but this is also a solution