# Unexpected navigation results?

Tags: html, css

I have a really simple navigation bar:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gqv88/1/

```
<nav>
    <div class="navTop">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Sub header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navBottom">
        <ul>
            <li id="btnHome">Home</li>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    background: url("img/escheresque_ste.png") repeat;
}
nav {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center; /* centre child content */
    background-color:black;
}
```

What this should do is create a div that spans the whole width of the page with some items inside, However when the page is made smaller (half screen view) and the scroll bar is moved, The navigation bar ends where the screen would end leaving a rather large gap on the right side. Any ideas?

Comment: Build a fiddle.  your code is incomplete, and it's unclear what you are saying the problem is.

Comment: @cale_b http://jsfiddle.net/Gqv88/1/ scroll right and you can see a large gap when it should be 100%;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462533/div-doesnt-stretch-100-width-of-a-page-if-window-width-narrower-then-the-rest

Comment: That *is* 100%. % refers to the screen width; if you look, it covers 100% of the screen width. The long line of h's is your problem.

Comment: Question is solved without an answer